# base_url including base address twice.and not loading bootstrap css file

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

new at codeigniter, trying simple code to load bootstrap css files with base_url() function.tried some answers on stackoverflow,but issue not solved.

**my view name is.... articles_list.php** 
**my controller name... user.php**

**i edit config.php as follow**  'localhost/ci';

**i edit autoload.php as follow** i load url helper in autoload.php

articles_list.php (loading css in view file)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css') ?>" >
```

**user.php(controller)**

```
$this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('public/articles_list');
```

when i run my view file, css is not loading, when i check view source it should give me both stylesheet url and link address as `"localhost/ci/assets/css/bootstrap.css"` but when i see view source it show `<link href="localhost/ci/assets/css/bootstrap.css">`  and when mouse over at link it shows me `localhost/ci/localhost/ci/assets/css/bootstrap.css` link address. please 
 help me to solve this issue and help me to learn codeigniter.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the `base_url` right in `application/config/config.php` file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';
```

And of course make sure to use the correct `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks sherif salah... after using http://, it is giving proper URL in view-source.